# Selecting 'one has many' mySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I've got two tables in mySQL. coffee_users and coffee_product_registrations. Each user can have multiple product registrations. I'm trying to select users with more than 1 product registration, but I'm getting the following error:

```
#1054 - Unknown column 'coffee_users.uid' in 'on clause'
```

When executing this:

```
SELECT c.uid
FROM 
  `coffee_users` as c
  JOIN (
    select uid
    from `coffee_users`
    group by `uid`
    having count(*)>1
  ) coffee_product_registrations
     on coffee_users.uid = coffee_product_registrations.uid
```

Is this doable at all?

Comment: Since you gave coffee_users an alias already, try changing it to `ON c.uid = coffee_product_registrations.uid`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is what you want?

```
SELECT c.uid 
FROM coffee_users c 
JOIN coffee_product_registrations cpr on c.uid = cpr.uid
GROUP BY c.uid 
HAVING COUNT(cpr.id) > 1
```

Comment: Notice that OP was using a self join. `coffee_product_registrations` is just an alias.

Comment: Oh, right. I didn't notice that. But the question states that there are indeed two tables so this should work, no?

Comment: Ah, you're right. Who knows where the problem lies, then.

Comment: @Bravi while I recommend this query over your first one, I believe changing `coffee_users` to `coffee_product_registrations` in the subquery would work. Regardless of whether that does or doesn't, I would still use this answer.

Comment: @McAdam331, yes that worked too. I just think this one is cleaner than my original post. So I've changed it to this one. Thanks guys.